# Python Pandas Debugging on to_datetime

Tags: python, string, datetime, debugging, pandas

Millions of records of data is in my dataframe.  I have to convert of the string columns to datetime.  I'm doing it as follows:

```
allData['Col1'] = pd.to_datetime(allData['Col1'])
```

However some of the strings are not valid datetime strings, and thus I get a value error.  I'm not very good at debugging in Python, so I'm struggling to find the reason why some of the data items are not convertible.

I need Python to show me the row number, as well as the value that is not convertible, instead of throwing out a useless error that tells me nothing.  How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) with condition where check `NaT` values by [`isnull`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.isnull.html) created [`to_datetime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_datetime.html) with parameter `errors='coerce'` - it create `NaT` where are invalid datetime:

```
allData1 = allData[pd.to_datetime(allData['Col1'], errors='coerce').isnull()]
```

Sample:

```
allData = pd.DataFrame({'Col1':['2015-01-03','a','2016-05-08'],
                        'B':[4,5,6],
                        'C':[7,8,9],
                        'D':[1,3,5],
                        'E':[5,3,6],
                        'F':[7,4,3]})

print (allData)
   B  C        Col1  D  E  F
0  4  7  2015-01-03  1  5  7
1  5  8           a  3  3  4
2  6  9  2016-05-08  5  6  3

print (pd.to_datetime(allData['Col1'], errors='coerce'))
0   2015-01-03
1          NaT
2   2016-05-08
Name: Col1, dtype: datetime64[ns]

print (pd.to_datetime(allData['Col1'], errors='coerce').isnull())
0    False
1     True
2    False
Name: Col1, dtype: bool


allData1 = allData[pd.to_datetime(allData['Col1'], errors='coerce').isnull()]
print (allData1)
   B  C Col1  D  E  F
1  5  8    a  3  3  4
```

Comment: For some reason if one error is detected, the whole column is made NaT.  Any ideas?

allData['GPS_DateTime'] = pd.to_datetime(allData['GPS_DateTime'], errors='coerce')

errorData = allData[allData['GPS_DateTime'].isnull()]

Comment: I think you need swap it: `errorData = allData[allData['GPS_DateTime'].isnull()]` is only for checking, so first check it and then convert to datetime by `allData['GPS_DateTime'] = pd.to_datetime(allData['GPS_DateTime'], errors='coerce')`

Comment: allData['GPS_DateTime'] = pd.to_datetime(allData['GPS_DateTime'], errors='coerce') gives a whole column of NaT

Comment: Can you send me your data as csv to email in my profile if not confidental data?

Comment: There is other code that is messing around - unfortunately it is confidential info.  Will see if I can find the problem

Comment: So if test it, what return `errorData` ? Because it return all rows, where are broken data. And then if use `allData['GPS_DateTime'] = pd.to_datetime(allData['GPS_DateTime'], errors='coerce')` all broken datetime are converted to `NaT`. It does not work with real data?

Comment: Sorry there was other code that changed the format of the datetime string.  I fixed it and now it is working.  Thanks for your help